# Jquery Selector use of not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have div having class name ".modalPopup" inside the div I have multiple table and inside table I have divs and inside the multiple controls like text box(input) and dropdownlists(select).

I want is that I want to fire click event when user click on any where on main div which have "modalPopup " except the dropdownlist(select).
I try using my options but I can't get the specific click event.
Like this:

```
  $('.modalPopup :not(modalPopup select)').click(function(){
    document.write("working for click except select ");
    });
```

Can any one please provide me the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to just bind the click event on the div with class of `modalPopup` and then check what the user actually clicked on using `e.target`:

```
$('.modalPopup').click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).is('select')) {
        document.write("working for click except select ");
    }
});
```

`e.target` is the dom element that was clicked. `$(e.target).is('select')` gets that dom element and created a jQuery object from it and checks if it is a select.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r9zqp/)

Comment: can you please expalain it "if (!$(e.target).is('select')) " . i am very thankful to you for that...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a dot before .modalPopup in the not() condition.

```
$('.modalPopup :not(.modalPopup select)').click(function(){ document.write("working for click except select "); });
```

Comment: i miss dot while typing here.. i find the solution.thanks for helping.